# What's wrong with my random search?

Tags: java

I get the error: "ArrayIndexOutOfBounds Exception3" I don't think that is the only error, but so far that's all I've been able to figure out.

```
import java.util.Random;
/*class containing random search algorithm*/
public class RandomSearch {
    public static int randomSearch(int queryValue, int[] list) {
    /*conducts a random search as specified by user*/
    /*trys 10,000,000 random combinations searching
      for user value*/
    int length = list.length;
    for(int i=0; i < 10000000; i++) {
        /*generates a random number from 0 to length*/
        int randomNum = (int)Math.floor(Math.random()*(length+1));
        StdOut.print(randomNum);
        if((int)queryValue == (int)list[randomNum]) {
         return randomNum;
        }
    }
    /*returns -2 if user value not found*/
    return -2;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've changed the line to, "int randomNum = (int)Math.floor(Math.random()*(length-1))" which got rid of the out of bounds error. The algorithm now works in all cases except when the queryValue is the last number in the array. Example queryValue = 3 and the array is [1, 2, 3].

Comment: I changed the it to "int randomNum = (int)Math.floor(Math.random()*(length)" and it works. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 2):

You need something like this to generate the index this gives the index between 0 and length
The  index you are generating is beyond the size of array thats why you are getting index out of bound exception.

```
/*Edit - Changed val to length to match the question.*/
public int randInt(int length) {

  // Usually this can be a field rather than a method variable
  Random rand = new Random();
  int randomNum = rand.nextInt(length);
  return randomNum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `randomNum` can get a value *larger* than the maximum index that can be used to access the array `list`.

To solve this, change

```
int randomNum = (int) (Math.random() * (length + 1));
```

to

```
int randomNum = (int) (Math.random() * (length));
```

Comment: That code can still produce error if `random()` returns `1`, or am I missing something?

Comment: No, I was wrong, `1.0` is not included, the correct interval is `[0.0; 1.0)` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random()

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your `list.length` length is 100, then if `Math.random()` return `0.999`, this statement

```
(int)Math.floor(Math.random()*(length+1));
```

will return `100`. While `100` is out of your list bounds, since valid indexes for array with length `100` are from `0` to `99`.

**Answer was updated** according to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random()

Comment: Math.random can never return 1

Answer (score 0):

Array indexes start at 0, so when you call length() on an array the last index will actually be length - 1. If you try any index after list[length - 1] you will get the Array out of bounds error.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use java.util.Random method:
`Random rand = new Random();`
`int randomNum = rand.nextInt(lenght+1);`
It gives u number from 1 to lenght.

Answer (score 0):

The standard approach is:

```
 int randomNum = (int)(Math.random()*length);
```

You don't need `Math.floor()` because casting to `int` has the same effect.

Also just multiply by `length` (not `length+1`, to give you numbers from 0 to length-1.

Or simply use the JDK's API:

```
int randomNum = new Random().nextInt(length);
```